# Passing value from php to mysql and back to javascript

Tags: php, html, mysql, google-maps

I'm working on google maps, and Im trying to categorize my markers by color. The category table has [id,categoryname,color], and the markers table has [id,....,category (id of category's table category)].

In PHP:

```
 $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `markers`");

    //Multiple rows are returned
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM))
    {

        if ( $x == 0 )
        {
             $separator = "";
        }
        else
        {
             $separator = "****";
        }
        //Saving to the String, each variable is separated by three &'s
        $encodedString = $encodedString.$separator.
            "<b><div class='name'></b>".$row[3].
        "</div><div class='opli'><b>Lon:</b> ".$row[2].
        "</div><div class='opli'><b>Lat:</b>".$row[1].
        "</div><div class='opli'><b>Address:</b>".$row[4].
        "</div><div class='opli'><b>Category:</b>".$row[5].
        "</div></div>&&&".$row[1]."&&&".$row[2]."&&&".$row[6]."&&&".$row[5];

        $x = $x + 1;
   $colorgetterq= mysql_query("SELECT color FROM `map`.`category` WHERE id= ".$row[5]."");
   $colorgettert = mysql_fetch_row($colorgetterq);
   $colorgetter= $colorgettert[0];
      }
```

in Java:
colorget = document.getElementById("colorget").value;

```
    stringArray = encodedString.split("****");

    var x;
    for (x = 0; x < stringArray.length; x = x + 1)
    {
        var addressDetails = [];
        var scale1 = [];
        var marker;
        //Separate each field
        addressDetails = stringArray[x].split("&&&");
        //Load the lat, long data
        var lat = new google.maps.LatLng(addressDetails[1], addressDetails[2]);
        //Create a new marker and info window


        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: lat,
            icon: {                
            strokeWeight: 0.01,
            fillColor: colorget,
            fillOpacity: 0.85,
             path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
             scale:  5 + addressDetails[3] * (35-5)/(hiscale-loscale),
            },
            content: addressDetails[0]
        });
```

I dont know what I'm doing is wrong but in the fillColor, for some reason the colors are still black, and wont load the different category colors.

Answer (score 0):

There are a bunch of problems here but lets just get this working for you.

Replace this line `$colorgetter= $colorgettert[0];` with `$encodedString= $encodedString."&&&" . $colorgettert[0];`

And this line `fillColor: colorget,` with `fillColor: addressDetails[6],`

Comment: ya i've used it directly before in the category field